# Conditional based on whether running in GitHub Action or elsewhere?

Tags: github, github-actions

How can I construct a conditional based on whether the code is running as a GitHub Action workflow or elsewhere?

#### Example

Suppose I want to run tests in headless browser on GitHub Actions workflows, but using a UI browser elsewhere.

Then this could work (in pseudocode, for demonstration):

```
on_github_action = ???

if !on_github_action
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome 
end
```

I'm just not sure how to figure out if it's running inside a GitHub Actions workflow? (I *think* this question is language-agnostic, but I'm using ruby, in case that's relevant).

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables? Although setting an env var that says which driver to use couples you far less to the infrastructure than asking "is this GHA?", the same technique works either way.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe is there a best practice or established norm? (I guess checking for the presence of any of the environment variables mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) would probably work?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @johnrsharpe for pointing out that you can [check for an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables) that will be in the GitHub Action workflow environment (but not in your local environment), for example `GITHUB_ACTION`:

```
if ENV["GITHUB_ACTION"].present? 
  ...
else
  ...
end
```